# Is possible to integrate react native into a JAR library?

Tags: android, react-native, jar

I need to build a application that could benefit from react-native integration. Is using a non-common toolchain (http://elementscompiler.com/) so I can't integrate it directly.

However, If I build a JAR it could work. However, [all the examples](https://codeburst.io/integrating-react-native-into-an-existing-app-android-c27bb1b81574) I have find are for integrations directly into the app. Is possible (and how?) to integrate react into a jar file, so I can import this to my project and use them?

So I need:

RN -> JAR -> App